# Add sitemap on application based on jhipster

Tags: angular, web-applications, jhipster, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I'm working with application generated with Jhipster.

I want add sitemap.xml and robot.txt but follow the angular conventions it seems not working.

I've created robot.txt and sitemap.xml under "src/main/webapp/".

in my angular.json file i've added

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "src/main/webapp/robots.txt",
              "src/main/webapp/sitemap.xml"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
```

how mentioned in [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options)

When i start application i not see sitemap.xml on localhost:8080/sitemap.xml not even in localhost:8080/main/webapp/robots.txt.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster does not (yet) fully support Angular CLI, so your changes in `angular.json` are not taken into account.

You need to modify the webpack configuration in `webpack/webpack.common.js` to copy `sitemap.xml` like what is already done for `robots.txt`.

By the way, `robots.txt` is already generated so you don't have to create it, just modify it.

Comment: i've see webpack.common.js, there is yet present configuration for robot.txt but if i go on mysite.com/robot.txt it return 404...

Comment: Just checking it's robots.txt with an  "s" not robot.txt. Have you run a prod build to check that the file has been bundled into your executable jar?